# MySql and PhP - Creating a ranking dropdown for a db column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take a column count for `moduleID` so that i can rank modules in a drop down as 1,2,3 not the moduleID. i want the count so that i can't rank more modules than there is available. this is what i have so far: but the ranking doesn't appear:

```
`<`!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Module Selector</title>
        <style>
            tr {background-color:lightblue;}
            td {text-align:center;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            require_once "includes/connection.inc.php";
            $conn = dbConnect();
            //echo 'connected';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM module";
                $nRows ="select moduleID, count(moduleID) from module"; 
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            try {
                $stmt->execute();
                $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
                if (!$results){ // check we have some results
                    echo "No modules Available at this Time try again later <br />";
                }
                else{   //generate table of modules
                    print "<table>\n";
                    echo "<th>ModuleID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Lecturer</th><th>Ranking</th>";
                    foreach ($results as $row){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["moduleID"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["ModuleName"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["ModuleDesc"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["LecturerID"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row[ $nRows]."</td>";
                    }
                    print "</table>\n";
                }
            } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
                echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
            // close database connection
            dbClose($conn);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `i am using PDO` - really? Looks like the old mysql extension to me...

Comment: can you provide the table definition?

Comment: For the record, you're NOT using PDO.  PDO code looks nothing like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT *, 
               (SELECT COUNT(moduleID) 
                FROM module 
                WHERE moduleID = 'MODULEID') as count 
       FROM module";
$get = mysql_query($sql);
```

Now you can get the count by using

```
$get_row['count']
```

Comment: sorry was confusing myself I'm supposed to be using PDO for this example but i cannot get it to work. i want to display the ranking in a drop down as 1,2,3 instead of the moduleID. but so i can't select more than the number for modules available i want to use a count. so this is my updated example using PDO: